# What are the standard colors for plots in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot

(**Note:** All the answers to this question are valid for versions of Mathematica before version 10. For versions 10 and above, see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54486/how-to-access-new-colour-schemes-in-version-10 and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54629/what-are-the-standard-colors-for-plots-in-mathematica-10.)

When using the **Plot** or **ListPlot** command in **Mathematica**, certain default colors are chosen.

For reasons of uniformity within some report I would like to use them along with the PlotStyle option. It turned out that I cannot reproduce the default colors with the [pre-defined color names](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/Colors.html), although blue and purple seem to be somehow close.

Hence my question:

> > How can I chose the standard colors used by Mathematica in plots along with PlotStyle?

Thank you in advance.

**Nice answers** were given by [belisarius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/353410/belisarius) and [Sjoerd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615464/sjoerd-c-de-vries) from which we can conclude that

> > Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[1, 4]]

will result in a sine plotted in the fourth standard color, some nice green.

Comment: Run `ColorData[1, "ColorList"]` to see all the colors given by their RGB vales.

Comment: Thank you for the additional hint, @Simon.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The colors used by Plot are in `ColorData[1]`.

Compare

```
Graphics[MapIndexed[{#1, 
    Tooltip[Rectangle[{#2[[1]], 0}, {#2[[1]] + 1, 1}], #1]} &, 
  ColorData[1] /@ Range[40]]]
```

[image]

with [Belisarius'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391825/what-are-the-standard-colors-for-plots-in-mathematica/5392280#5392280) colors

```
Graphics[MapIndexed[{#1, 
    Tooltip[Rectangle[{#2[[1]], 0}, {#2[[1]] + 1, 1}], #1]} &, 
  Cases[ListPlot[Table[{i}, {i, 40}]], Hue[x__], Infinity]]]
```

[image]

They are the same, except one is terms of `Hue` and the other in terms or `RGBColor`

Comment: I'm afraid this is not true for Mathematic 10 anymore. With the introduction of PlotThemes a lot changed. The default plot scheme accessible by `ColorData` is `ColorData[97, x]` as pointed out in this thread: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54629/what-are-the-standard-colors-for-plots-in-mathematica-10

Answer (score 20):

I know this is *really* late to the game, but the expression used to *generate* the `n`th color in `ColorData[1]` is:

```
Hue[FractionalPart[0.67 + 2.0 (i - 1)/GoldenRatio], 0.6, 0.6]
```

**Update** Based on Alexey's comment below, you can find this using:

```
ColorData[1] // InputForm
```

Comment: +1. Interesting. We can get this with `ColorData[1] // InputForm`.

Comment: Wow, wouldn't have thought of that. I found this digging through the `PlotLegends` package.

Comment: @Alexey I think yours is the definitive answer for this question

Comment: @belisarius Not really. The question wasn't how ColorData[1] is generated, but what color scheme is used by Plot.

Comment: @Sjoerd - Oh, come on Sjoerd, the formula gives you the same information as the table. In fact, most of the time I prefer a formula; it's easier to convert the formula to a table than the other way around. +1

Answer (score 12):

If you do:

```
ListPlot[Table[{i}, {i, 10}]] // FullForm
```

You get the first 10 Hues used.

Or this gives you a ready to use list:

```
hues = Cases[ListPlot[Table[{i}, {i, 10}]], Hue[x__], Infinity]

{Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6],     Hue[0.906068, 0.6, 0.6], 
 Hue[0.142136, 0.6, 0.6], Hue[0.378204, 0.6, 0.6], 
 Hue[0.614272, 0.6, 0.6], Hue[0.85034, 0.6, 0.6], 
 Hue[0.0864079, 0.6, 0.6],Hue[0.322476, 0.6, 0.6], 
 Hue[0.558544, 0.6, 0.6], Hue[0.794612, 0.6, 0.6]}
```

Usage sample:

```
SphericalPlot3D[\[Phi], {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, {\[Phi], 0, 3 Pi},
 Epilog -> 
  Table[Inset[Framed[Style["Spiral", 20],
        Background -> hues[[i]]],
             {i/15 + .1, i/15}], 
  {i, 10}]]
```

[image]

If you prefer the RGB color space you may do:

```
rgbs= ColorConvert[#, "RGB"] & /@ hues
```

**Edit ** Comparing with Eli's formula:

```
mine = Cases[ListPlot[Table[{i}, {i, 10}]], Hue[x__], Infinity]
elis = Table[Hue[FractionalPart[0.67 + 2.0 (i-1)/GoldenRatio],0.6,0.6], {i,1,10}]
Chop[(mine- elis) /. Hue[x_, __] -> x]
(* -> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

Great, Eli!

Comment: Thank you for the nice workaround, I did not know of the use of FullForm :)

Comment: @Robert Filter `FullForm` is your friend. Use it anywhere to closer understand what's going on internally.